# spinnaker cors issue with gate api

Tags: tomcat8, spinnaker

I am getting below error while accessing spinnaker on private IP.

> Failed to load http://privateip:8084/webhooks/preconfigured: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://privateip:9000' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I have added base url by using below hal config command.

```
hal config security ui edit --override-base-url "privateip"
hal config security api edit --override-base-url "privateip"
```

Does anyone know how to fix above error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this: 
`hal config security api edit --cors-access-pattern privateip` 
No double quotes needed. 
Check here the docs: https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/halyard/commands/#hal-config-security-api-edit

Answer (score 0):

The `--override-base-url` is mostly used for when you assign a DNS address. You don't need it to specify that argument when using raw IPs.

Comment: Unless you're overriding it to specify the IP of the fronting load balancer. Then you might need to override with a raw IP. I'd suggest giving it a proper DNS name - it'll make your life easier.